# How do I mapping Ctrl+Middle to Right-Click in X?

Tags: xmodmap

How do I mapping `Ctrl+Middle` to `Right-Click` in X?

I aware "window manager"+"xdotool"  maybe is a way,but such things now working for window manager itself and also possible more unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use xbindkeys and xvkbd.
~/.xbindkeyrc

```
"xvkbd -text '\m3'"
   control + b:2
```

Comment: Your answer(tell me two powerful tool) is useful for me,but not for this question.I want do native mapping as `xmodmap` ,not run a shell command.

Comment: Then use the source, Luke!